# Adding JQuery to Intellij

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellij-idea

Is this how you add jquery to intellij? I'm getting JS errors in my web application, so I figured I incorporated JQuery incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: Have you applied for Jquery from settings libraries?

Comment: I read that on the internet somewhere, but didnt really find it in my project. I looked again and found it and it worked thanks lol.